# dotcloud celery permission denied

Tags: django, celery, dotcloud

I am attempting to use celery in my django application so that I can run a background process that imports a CSV file into the one of my models databases. This works fine on my local machine running a celery worker using:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

and RabbitMQ

```
rabbitmq-server
```

This is the error I receive once I push to dotcloud

```
workers.0    celery.platforms.LockFailed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/celeryev.pid'
```

EDIT:

```
supervisord.conf

[program:djcelery]
command = /home/dotcloud/env/bin/python /home/dotcloud/current/cellhelmet/manage.py celeryd -E -l info -c 2
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_error.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log

[program:celerycam]
command = /home/dotcloud/env/bin/python /home/dotcloud/current/cellhelmet/manage.py     celerycam
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_error.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
```

Comment: What is the environment you are using? Check this link: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had removed this line from the supervisord.conf file:

```
directory = /home/dotcloud/current/cellhelmet
```

That caused it to search from the root directory i'm assuming which gave me the permission denied error. It certainly cleared it up for me though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to write a pid file to / which makes sense why you would get a permission denied.

What do you have for a value for `CELERYD_PID_FILE` ?

Try setting it to one of these options

CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/log/supervisor/%n.pid"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/home/dotcloud/"

More info about your config options can be found here: http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html

If that doesn't work can you let us know how you are kicking off the command and send along any configuration (supervisord.conf, etc) and scripts you are using to run celery.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your help. I followed the docs located here http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/tutorials/python/django-celery/ and it didn't mention where to place the settings. I tried placing the option you mentioned above in my settings.py file but it had no effect. Where should I place those settings?

Comment: I tried *dotcloud env set CELERYD_PID_FILE=celery.pid* with no luck and even changed my supervisord.conf to "command = python manage.py celeryd -E -l info -c 2 --pidfile celeryd.pid" but still receiving the same error.

Comment: @ChrisC sorry to hear it didn't help. Please send an email to support@dotcloud.com with the name of your application, and we will help you figure out the issue. Reference this stack overflow question  as well.